# Alexaの定型アクションの実行時間を声で指定したい

Tags: untagged

目覚まし代わりに、スイッチボットと組み合わせてAlexaの定型アクションを使っています。
電気を少しずつ明るくする、テレビをつける、現在の時刻を読み上げるのなどを指定時間に実行するような定型アクションです。

これらアクションの実行条件は毎日起きる時間を変えるので、毎日手動で実行時間を設定しています。これが結構煩わしいです。
ここを声で指定することはできないでしょうか。以下のようなイメージです。

- 「Alexa, 明日6時に目覚ましアクションをセットして」
- 「定型アクションAの実行条件を、6時にセットしました」

IFFFTなどのサードパーティーソフトの組み合わせなどで実現できる方法がないか、ヒントをいただけますと幸いです。

また、このような動作を行わせるためのプログラムを走らせるソフト?などはありますでしょうか。
Alexaが聞き取った時間を変数に入れて、アクションに渡せればよいのですが、このようなことを実装する方法がわかりません。

参考になるサイトなども併記いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。